# Why does my reputation not add up?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, voting, accepted-answer

Hi, I joined the StackOverflow site today and have a question about the reputation. According to the FAQ, you can get reputation for the following 2 things (amongst others):

- Your Question or Answer is voted Helpful: +10 reputation
- Your Answer is marked Accepted: +15 reputation OR the full amount of the bounty, if any

Looking at the answers I've given in my profile, I have a total of 20 up votes across 9 different answers, 3 of which were accepted. I actually had 4 accepted answers earlier on, but one became unaccepted when a better answer was offered.

I also understand that users start with 1 reputation and can gain up to 200 reputation points in a day, so earlier today, I had 201 reputation points, which is the limit. This all makes sense so far.

Suddenly, I noticed that my reputation points had gone down to 186, but I can't seem to make it all add up. Adding up just the up-votes, discounting the fact that some answers were accepted, gives 200 points for that alone. I checked, and I hadn't been voted down on any answers.

The only explanation I can think of is that my reputation reached the 200 limit with 4 accepted answers and 16 up-votes, after which I received 4 more up votes, which weren't counted due to the fact that I was at the limit. When one of the answers became unaccepted, I lost the 15 points for it, bringing me back down to 186. However, those 40 points that weren't counted for the up-votes I received earlier aren't counted now, despite the fact that I have less than 200 reputation for today.

I'm not particularly bothered by it, but I thought I would at least raise it to see if I'm missing something obvious, or if it is perhaps a potential bug (albeit, not a very serious one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've hit the nail on the head.  The system just discards rep from upvotes beyond 200, which means that if something else happens which lowers your rep below the 200 cap, that other rep no longer exists to bring it back up.

Comment: If you want to reset this to the correct value, open the [reputation audit](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and click **Trigger Rep Recalc**.  This can be demanding on the servers, so you can only do this once per 24 hours.  See [Self-instigated rep recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Although this behaviour was intended and expected back in 2009 when you asked the question, the situation has changed since; [in February 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123319/347902), large-scale changes to the reputation counter were made which caused unaccepts to adjust to the reputation cap correctly, both in terms of the displayed value and in erms of the actual value internally. So this is no longer a problem nowadays.