# Why doesn't the reputation audit trigger a rep recalc?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-audit, reputation-recalc

It's my understanding that the reputation on my profile gets desynched from my "real" reputation for a variety of reasons. It's also my understanding that the reputation shown on the rep audit (https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) is the "real" reputation.

So why can't the system update my reputation to the one on the audit every time I open it? I mean, it's not like it's going to use a lot of resources, since it's already got the total there - just one more `UPDATE` query and it should be done.

This would sure be a lot better than having to bother moderators to do it for you.

> **EDIT:** This is basically [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc/71678#71678).

Comment: It's a good idea, but a button somewhere would be nice, just so you know you asked for the recalc. I think just auto-recalculating your reputation when you view the audit violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: See also Waffles' answer at [Trigger a rep recalc any time a post is deleted/undeleted or question migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80898/trigger-a-rep-recalc-any-time-a-post-is-deleted-undeleted-or-question-migrated/80916#80916).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I upvoted it but these are just workarounds and there is a much better solution, which is also relatively easy to implement: **reputation should never become out of sync**.

How difficult can it possibly be to remove the reputation from upvotes/etc when a question gets migrated or deleted, for example?

Comment: The problem is that it makes people unhappy if their reputation goes down, and making people unhappy is bad for the site. Therefore deletions/... don't really show up in your reputation and I guess it will stay that way.

Comment: @sth: Except they *do* show up in your reputation, whenever you get recalculated.

Comment: @Jon: But there only once was a recalculation (for the average user) and I don't think there will come any more soon. So once every few years there might come a day when you loose some reputation. That's much easier to bear than if it happens over and over again in smaller doses.

Comment: As mentioned above 'principle of least surprise'. Reputation changes should be *traceable*. Deletions are not.

Comment: @devinb: according to your absurd reasoning then if I upvote a person and then remove the vote, that person should retain the rep until a "rep recalc", when they'll mysteriously lose a bunch of rep. This is much less surprising.

Comment: @Kop Votes are locked in after 5 minutes. Unless I edit my question, and then they can edit their votes. This leaves a relatively limited number of places where votes can be changed around. Furthermore, vote *changes* on old questions are rare. Also, which part of my *reasoning* is absurd. My reasoning is sound, the outcome might be absurd.

Comment: Changing votes is just as rare as questions being deleted.

Answer (score 1):

People care very strongly about their reputations. The reputations are, in fact, the main reason why most people are answering questions. They'll answer a few questions to start, but day to day, it's because they want that number to keep ticking upward.

Every time that number changes there is an *accessible log*. Whenever my reputation changes I can immediately go into my recent changes for the last day and see why. Reputation Audits don't do that. Your reputation changes *without any record*. Deletions, vote-pattern detectors, they fall into that.

If my reputation goes down by 100 all at once, I'm going to want to know why, and there simply isn't a record of it.

Even the rep-audit doesn't help with that, because it contains the record of everything that *adds up* to your current rep, but it will never show the things that were *removed*.

This is why recalcs are by buy-in only. They will affect your reputation in unknown and *unknowable* ways.

Comment: The point being?

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, accessing the requested feature means knowing that your reputation is going to change. I don't think he's asking for more accounting on why rep went away.

Comment: @Null The last sentence explains why I do not want your feature request. I don't want the act of *viewing* my reputation to automatically *change* it.

Comment: Note that also just a normal votes that someone takes back is also not traceable. And did you mean "*recalcs* are by buy-in only"?

Comment: @sth Thanks for pointing that out :D

Comment: @sth vote retractions can only happen within 5 minutes of the vote, or if you edit your post, so there are relatively few occasions where they would happen.