# Requesting /reputation should save recalculated reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't the reputation audit trigger a rep recalc?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63011/why-doesnt-the-reputation-audit-trigger-a-rep-recalc)

Observe that visiting

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

provides you with a fully up-to-date, 'real' reputation result which often differs from the one normally shown, which lags and is inaccurate from deleted posts, etc.

If requesting that 'hidden' page made the system go to the trouble of recalculating the reputation, then the system should take that opportunity to use that recalculation as a recalculation on your main, public reputation.

Comment: I sure love being trampled to death. In any case, this has been requested a fair amount. I'll try to find the exact one for this... or someone beat me to it! Hah! Now people can shut up about how I always find these!

Comment: @Grace Note: actually, I was about to post "Grace'll certainly find a dupe" [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64729/real-and-shown-reputation-differ) ;p

Comment: @Tobias Well, since you asked...

Comment: @Grace, I'm fairly sure you rigged this by intentionally moving slowly. That, or I've stumbled upon your sockpuppet network....

Answer (score 0):

The reputation shown at the top of the page will match the "actual" reputation displayed on https://stackoverflow.com/reputation when a global re-calculation is performed.

Performing a Global Recalc is a massive hit on the CPU so it's not done daily.

You will have to see if Jeff or someone else with a bit of clout answers this question as they will probably know when this occurs.  It appears to be a bit of a secret.

Here is a long discussion about introducing a [self instigated rep recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc)

Comment: You can also request an individual recalc from diamonds by flagging for moderator attention.

Comment: Flagging what, exactly? There is no 'flag' link on my account page, for example.