# Reputation changes strangely

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've observed something quite strange on my StackOverflow account reputation.
At beginning of this month my reputation was 2,315. Then one day suddenly it's downed to 2,289. Assuming that someone played around and I didn't consider it.
There was reputation log (-2) on many of my posts.
However, in the next several days, my reputation was downed to 2,263 but there is no reputation log; including all above reputation log.

(call this First Event) 
First: 2,315 -> Down w/ Log (-26): 2,289 -> Continuous Down w/ All Log Removed: (-26, the same number): 2,263.

(this is Second Event) 
But from this morning til mid-day:
First: 2,263 -> Down w/ Log (-16): 2,247 -> Up w/ All Log Removed: (+16): 2,263.

I'm wondering about this strange behaviors. Any explanation?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you were a serial downvoting victim. When the system detects this, it will revert all the downvotes and recalculate your reputation.

So this is probably what happenned:

1. You start with 2315. Then you get a serially downvoted down to 2289.
2. The serial voting script catches this and reverts all the downvotes. (they no longer appear in your rep-history)
3. Your reputation is then recalculated -> 2263
4. The downvoter realizes all the votes were reverted and downvotes you again. 2263 -> 2247
5. The script picks it up again, reverts them, and recalculates your rep. (back to 2263)

Your actual reputation can get out of sync with your visible reputation for a number of reasons including (but not limited to): deleted posts, migrated posts, etc...

The reputation recalc will resync your rep, that's why your reputation dropped from 2315 to 2263 after the whole series of events. (See Tim Post's comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113594/169611).)

Comment: interesting, but I still don't get from 2 to 3, why recalculation is to get down, instead of up?

Comment: That would be because your actual rep (stackoverflow.com/reputation) was 2263 all along. But your visible rep was at 2315 to start. They can get out of sync for the reasons I mentioned. For example, if a post gets deleted, you lose all the rep that you gained/lost on it. But it isn't reflected in your visible rep until the next recalc.

Comment: oh, I get the point :)