# Wrong Rep Count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I've recently discovered the [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and Checked it that there it says I have 473 rep points, and on my SO account it shows me 471[image]

So where can this be wrong?

Log from Reputation

---

```
total votes: 86
 2   1499487 (10)
-- 2009-10-02 rep +10   = 11        
 2   1519829 (10)
-- 2009-10-05 rep +10   = 21        
 3   1526942 (-2)
-- 2009-10-06 rep -2    = 19        
 2   1519829 (10)
 1   1519829 (15)
-- 2009-10-09 rep +25   = 44        
 2   1572137 (10)
-- 2009-10-16 rep +10   = 54        
-- 2009-10-19 rep 0     = 54        
 1   1588674 (2)
-- 2009-10-24 rep +2    = 56        
 2   1627255 (10)
 1   1627255 (15)
-- 2009-10-27 rep +25   = 81        
 2   1709935 (10)
-- 2009-11-10 rep +10   = 91        
 2   1709935 (10)
-- 2009-11-11 rep +10   = 101       
-- 2009-11-19 rep 0     = 101       
 2   2049660 (5)
-- 2010-01-12 rep +5    = 106       
 2   1840118 (10)
-- 2010-02-17 rep +10   = 116       
-- 2010-02-23 rep 0     = 116       
 3    984607 (-1)
-- 2010-03-09 rep -1    = 115       
 3    680408 (-1)
-- 2010-03-19 rep -1    = 114       
-- 2010-04-10 rep 0     = 114       
 2   1588348 (5)
-- 2010-04-14 rep +5    = 119       
-- 2010-04-20 rep 0     = 119       
 2   2479334 (10)
 1   2685421 (15)
-- 2010-04-21 rep +25   = 144       
 2   2684707 (10)
 2   2686743 (10)
 2   2692702 (10)
 2   2693885 (10)
 2   2692254 (10)
-- 2010-04-22 rep +50   = 194       
 1   2692254 (15)
-- 2010-04-23 rep +15   = 209       
 1   2686743 (15)
-- 2010-04-26 rep +15   = 224       
 1   2716210 (15)
 2   2716926 (5)
 3   2497453 (-1)
-- 2010-04-27 rep +19   = 243       
-- 2010-04-28 rep 0     = 243       
 2   2731596 (10)
-- 2010-04-29 rep +10   = 253       
 2   2731836 (10)
-- 2010-05-14 rep +10   = 263       
 2   1526942 (10)
-- 2010-05-24 rep +10   = 273       
-- 2010-05-28 rep 0     = 273       
-- 2010-05-29 rep 0     = 273       
-- 2010-06-01 rep 0     = 273       
 2   3056014 (10)
 1   3056014 (15)
 3   3056014 (-2)
 3   2930570 (-2)
 2   3056014 (10)
 2   3056014 (10)
-- 2010-06-16 rep +41   = 314       
 2   3056014 (10)
-- 2010-06-17 rep +10   = 324       
 2   2929647 (10)
-- 2010-06-25 rep +10   = 334       
-- 2010-07-23 rep 0     = 334       
 2   3344193 (10)
 2   3344193 (10)
-- 2010-07-27 rep +20   = 354       
 2   3344193 (10)
-- 2010-07-28 rep +10   = 364       
 1   3469069 (15)
 2   2929958 (10)
-- 2010-08-12 rep +25   = 389       
 2   1840118 (10)
-- 2010-08-19 rep +10   = 399       
-- 2010-08-24 rep 0     = 399       
 2   3569037 (10)
-- 2010-08-25 rep +10   = 409       
-- 2010-08-26 rep 0     = 409       
 2   3622105 (5)
 1   3623710 (2)
-- 2010-09-02 rep +7    = 416       
 1   3653784 (2)
 2   3653756 (5)
-- 2010-09-06 rep +7    = 423       
-- 2010-09-10 rep 0     = 423       
-- 2010-09-17 rep 0     = 423       
 2   3813567 (10)
-- 2010-09-29 rep +10   = 433       
-- 2010-09-30 rep 0     = 433       
 2   3865306 (10)
-- 2010-10-05 rep +10   = 443       
 2   3891144 (10)
-- 2010-10-08 rep +10   = 453       
 2   3588188 (10)
-- 2010-10-18 rep +10   = 463       
 2   1840118 (10)
-- 2010-11-01 rep +10   = 473       

** total rep 473 :)

days represented 51
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
rep cap was exceeded on 0 days
```

Comment: This is nothing unusual. The displayed rep often does not match the reputation report (when in doubt, the latter is the one that is up-to-date). You'd have to request a [rep recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/) (I wouldn't bother because of just two points), or wait for the next [global rep recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/) (which doesn't happen all too often).

Comment: @RegDwight But which one of these reps counts for gaining privileges on SO?

Comment: For all I know from personal experience, the displayed rep is the one that counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is denormalized so it is standard for it to be slightly out of date based on users getting deleted, posts getting deleted, and so forth.

Comment: But which one is used to grant privs on SO?

Answer (score -1):

[Changes to the rep system are being made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), so that your displayed rep (used for determining privileges) will never be out of sync with the rep shown in the audit at [/reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation).  In essence, your reputation will always be correct, irrespective of deletions or other activity not previous tracked.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?