# Reputation: recalc report typo

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, spelling

If you attempt to recalculate your reputation more than one time per day, the following message is shown:

> Reputation cannot be recalculated more
>   then once per day.

Correct: 'more th*a*n once'.

Also, there's some lag with recalc, even when it is forced: prevents high server loads?

I am glad to be helping you, your Grammar Nazi.

Comment: Oh SHI-- People, I've just lost 80 rep after triggering a recalc: from 1793 to 1713! Can I get it back!? :-(

Comment: No, that is the point of the recalc. To see why your rep would have dropped, refer to this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74905/why-did-recalculating-my-rep-make-it-go-down/

Comment: @Brandon: I remember, I havent posted to CW though, and it seems none of questions is CW now. Okay.

Comment: This is the same on english.stackexchange.com, kinda funny? 'Reputation cannot be recalculated more then once per day.'

Comment: @Radek S: I guess it'll change on the next reload of their platform :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, this is by design. You see, the character `a` is ASCII 97, which is `01100001` in binary. On the other hand, `e` is ASCII 101, or `01100101`.

As I'm sure you know, zeros are more expensive <strike>then</strike> than ones to send over a network connection (because they're well-rounded and hence heavier).

And since Stack Overflow currently has lots of problems with bandwidth (ever since a clueless intern caused our network load to skyrocket by [sending unneccessary newlines across the internet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76523/why-stackoverflow-wastes-4-bytes-when-outputting-the-web-site-closed)), we have to save where we can.

We were hoping no-one would notice this.

But alas, you did.

So we fixed it.

Thanks.

:)

Comment: ... (express of astonishment)

Comment: @balpha: LOL. Oh noes, you just wasted 100 KiB of SE traffic by posting your answer :-) BTW, should I accept the answer?

Comment: +1. I like my bytes well rounded.

Comment: @badp: +1 for getting the reference :)

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev: Accept if you want to; this is Meta, it doesn't really matter. BTW, I would've received a notification of your comment even before your edit; the owner of the post you're commenting on always gets notified, whether you include a @reply or not.

Comment: @balpha: I suspected about notice, but I've edited the comment (I fail at English) several times, and after the 2nd edit just added @ to ensure you'll get back to read the comment again. ;-)

Comment: +1 for referring to the most stupid question ever. :)