# Solving the issue of reputation recalculation

Tags: discussion, reputation

I read several instances ([here is one instance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc/14201#14201)) where recalculating reputation was described as an expensive operation; therefore, it was concluded, that it should not be done frequently, nor should users have the privilege to recalculate their own reputation unless they request the operation from a moderator.

Wouldn't adding a `recepientId` column to the votes table solve such a problem? Would the overhead of adding an additional column to the database table not be offset by the benefit of recalculating with a few, if any, table joins and what not?

**EDIT**: It came to light (thanks Pollyanna) that [users can now recalculate](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) their own reputation. I'm more interested in the merits of my suggestion; in that, would it make sense to add a recepientId column to the votes table, and how advantageous would that be?

Comment: Mel, it's not clear to me how your suggestion addresses the performance concern around reputation calculation. Can you expand on your ideas?

Comment: @Michael, the votes table stores the id of the voter and the post. The id of the recipient and the post type must be inferred from the post. Those two elements are taken into account for reputation. Also, in the case of accepted answers, the question is required (you can't get rep if you own the accepted answer and the question); this must be inferred from the parentId of the post. Now that I thought about it, it doesn't make sense; having the recepientId will not solve all the problems. The postType is still needed. Now you need to add postType & recipeintId, & possibly other cols! Ignore me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Reputation recalculation is now available as a user-initiated operation at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation (button at bottom).</strike>

Whether it's a CPU expensive operation or not, it's something they now let users perform if desired.

In early 2012 this became redundant as [reputation is now correct at all times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes). The button to initiate a reputation recalc was subsequently removed.

Comment: could you please weigh in on the merits of my suggestion?

Comment: @Mel - No, I don't know enough about the internal architecture of the Stack Overflow engine to comment on performance improvements.  Perhaps one of the Stack Overflow Valued Associates will chime in here.

Comment: In my experience a recalculation is likely to lose points; I'm unwilling to do it voluntarily because I'd slip in the rankings. I've struggled to stay on page 5 for just about my entire existence on the site.

Comment: @Mark: but if everyone got recalculated periodically, then on average, most people would stay in about the same place in the rankings.  I'm sympathetic to the view that the reputations on the first couple of pages of users for a site should be routinely recalculated periodically - say weekly or monthly.  I tend to keep my score accurate; I dislike database systems that are inaccurate, but my work colours my perspective on such things.

Comment: @AdamDavis, There's **no button** at the bottom. Nowhere in the page, Am I missing something?

Comment: @Pacerier No, the button was removed awhile ago as they fixed the problems that led to reputation not always being up to date.  Thus there should now never be a need for a recalculation as the reputation is never out of sync. I've updated my answer and added a link to the relevant meta post regarding the change.

Comment: @AdamDavis, Argh, too much meta to wade through.