# New activity dropdown gives incorrect week total for reputation

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, activity-dropdown

The new activity dropdown seems to be a bit confused. It says I earned 65 rep this week, yet it clearly links to a page which shows that I've earned 75 rep this week. Normally, I would put this down to caching, but the "today" column was updating just fine when this was actively occurring (go to revision history for this post if you want to see the earlier image).

The discrepancy seems to be constantly 10, so maybe this is an edge condition with a retracted upvote (maybe a vote, unvote, and then another vote either in the five minutes or maybe after an edit).

[image: image of incorrect number]

Comment: @ChrisF is correct, the week reset is on sunday at 00:00 UTC for the dropdown, the `/users` page, and the stackexchange.com rep leagues.

Comment: @Nick That notwithstanding, I fail to understand how I can earn 50 rep today (actually, yesterday by now) but only 40 for the week as of yesterday. Surely the week always contains today?

Comment: Wouldn't it be worthwhile to put a line of gray text on the hover thingy, beneath rep points, saying "*Week rep calculated since Sunday 00:00 UTC*" and other significant points. After all the real UTC time is happily ticking away in the bottom corner looking lonely without some accompanying context.

Comment: @Nick Craver: I'm wait waiwai933 here. In what circumstances could rep gained "today" not count towards "this week"? Surely the day starts at 00:00 UTC, and so does the week (if it's Sunday). How is this "by design"?

Comment: I can see through that red cross out!

Comment: @muntoo You can also go to the revision history if you're really curious and don't want your eyes to bleed.

Comment: @Jon - that is indeed a bug I'll get into probably tomorrow morning, may be a week reset issue with the timing.  We've been dealing with other urgent issues the past few days, just now getting back to the bug list.

Comment: @Jon - This actually isn't a bug, see my answer below in a moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The week reset is covered in comments above, we reset at 00:00 UTC, now for the 10 rep difference:

The week/month/etc changes are the **net change** in that period (e.g. `endRep - startRep`), so why doesn't this *seem* to match [your rep report](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/100/waiwai933?tab=reputation)?

After you edited [your answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/is-it-a-uniform-or-an-uniform/4701#4701) someone reversed their upvote on it (on 2011-03-16), meaning you lost that 10 rep.  So for the week, you lost 10, brining your week change down to 65.

---

**Update:** In the next build "today" will behave the same as the other intervals, like week, month, quarter and year.  Every interval now means:

> "How much did your rep change from the beginning of [the X"

To be as explicit as possible:

- **today** - "How much did my rep change from the beginning of **today**?"
- **week** - "How much did my rep change from the beginning of the **week**?"
- **month** - "How much did my rep change from the beginning of the **month**?"
- **quarter** - "How much did my rep change from the beginning of the **quarter**?"
- **year** - "How much did my rep change from the beginning of the **year**?"

These meanings apply everywhere: currently the user popup and the `/users` page.

For example (related to this question):

If you got **10** upvotes for **100** rep today, but someone reversed an upvote from months ago (but they did so *today*) then you would see **+90** as the change today, since from the beginning of the day your total rep went up **90**.

You should only see this mis-match from the "votes today" on your reputation profile tab when  someone reverses their vote (due to an edit, etc).  If this is too much to bear, you can [recalc your reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc/71678#71678) which will sync up all history and not show that previous increase (or the corresponding decrease from the reversal) ever happened.

Comment: So daily rep changes aren't done on the same basis? I think I see how it works, but I hope you agree it's pretty confusing. Probably not worth reworking though...

Comment: @Jon - Daily is indeed by vote totals, so it may be worth redoing...we'll discuss it on the next team call - the old revoked vote honestly wasn't considered that heavily the first round, we'll have to think if this is the best way to present that.  There's a more visible potential issue with daily if our reset doesn't happen at precisely the right time, which in an outage can *potentially* happen.

Comment: @Jon - In the next deploy, we'll switch today to be a delta as well, how much did your rep *actually change* from the beginning of the day.

Comment: Fab. Does that mean I'll be able to see where I've lost points due to an accepted answer (from a different day) being unaccepted? Or will it show that the rep has been lost, but without a link?

Comment: @Jon - without a link at the moment, we're mulling showing this, but leaning towards no...since showing deleted votes would be a whole can of worms

Answer (score 4):

March 10th and 12th were last week.

The figure isn't for the last 7 days, but for the week starting Sunday. In this case Sunday 13th March. In which case you have earned 50 rep this week.

The other 39 was last week.

BTW - you might want to obscure which post you down-voted ;)

**UPDATE**

However that does leave a discrepancy of 10 which I can't explain.

Comment: 50 rep this week, not 40 though. It still looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Jon - Ah - missed that subtlety. Caching perhaps?