# Strange rep. computation after undeleting answer with upvotes

Tags: support, reputation, undelete

This is what I see if I open the new popup window with my profile:

[image]

I think today's reputation should not be higher then week reputation. I got this result after these steps:

1. I answered question and received 2 upvotes
2. Somebody else answered the question. His answer was exact opposite of my answer and was accepted so I rashly decided to delete my answer and I also triggered reputation recalculation.
3. I tried provided solution and I found that it doesn't work as expected. I undeleted my answer and modified it to explain what I found.

Comment: I guess the values are cached. So wait a little bit.

Comment: IMO it is "reputation leak". I expect that if I trigger reputation recalculation tommorow it will add +20.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New activity dropdown gives incorrect week total for reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83495/new-activity-dropdown-gives-incorrect-week-total-for-reputation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think meta needs some more detail around this, so I'll copy my answer [from here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/day-vs-week-rep-gain/1825#1825):

> It's not a different cut-off time, but
>   rather how we calculate it, for
>   "today" we count up the votes that
>   happened today, where as with a week
>   we track the net change throughout the
>   week.
>
> I'm going to look at changing this
>   tomorrow (so that the day does the
>   same as other intervals).  There are
>   pros/cons on both solutions, but the
>   consistency might be worth it here.
>
> Here's the common case that leads to
>   this:  A vote is deleted or undeleted
>   that was *previously* created, this
>   makes display a bit wacky since we
>   don't show *removed* votes, or
>   undeleted votes in the time they had
>   the net effect, let's take an example:
>
> - May: someone votes your post up, +10
>
>   - your rep goes up 10 for the week, month, etc.
> - June: say you edited later, someone removes that vote (or unaccepts an
>     answer)
>
>   - your rep goes down 5/10/15, etc for the week, month, etc.
>
> Now from the *day* point of view
>   (strictly looking at that range), your
>   rep hasn't changed, no vote happened
>   *then*.  However, there was a *net* effect on your rep, it's just that the
>   10 rep was removed (looking overall)
>   back in may...or rather it no longer
>   happened.

We're not done with this, we're still refining the display, there will be more improvements this week, but I can't say for certain which direction they'll go...since it's not a simple temporal problem, both to calculate and display.