# Bug after downvote and then edit accepted caused -9 change to rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

1. [Edited a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740178/remove-the-color-of-word-or-keywords-when-press-backspace-or-delete-key-in-the-ri)
2. [Downvoted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740267/shared-database-connectivity)
3. Previous edit was accepted by a moderator

The rep log shows -1 then +2, but is totaled as -9. I expected the total rep to be calculated as +1.

[image]

UPDATE

Looks accurate...

```
 3   5740267 (-1)
 16  5740178 (2)
 2   5740098 (10)
 2   5739901 (10)
 1   5739901 (15)
-- 2011-04-21 rep +36   = 605
```

I was unaware of the tool. Very nice.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/reputation show different numbers for today?

Comment: Triggering recalc fixed the total as displayed in the header. Not a bug? Just me being an impatient user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone probably removed an upvote on one of your answers. While this is reflected in the net daily rep change, it is not recorded as a separate action (instead, it simply removes the previous vote from history).

Comment: That's a reasonable answer, except the daily rep total shouldn't show a negative value. In this case, at the time of the screen shot, it should still have been +1.

Comment: Revoked upvotes show on history? Is that a new feature?

Comment: @Ed From the start of today UTC, you dropped 9 rep, which is why it shows -9. The values there are net change for the time range, which includes revoked votes.

Comment: @YOU They don't show up except in the net change amounts (you can't see them individually)—see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83495/new-activity-dropdown-gives-incorrect-week-total-for-reputation/83804#83804) for further details.

Comment: That link is helpful. Jon Skeet made the same argument I was making and was given the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

[As the new reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) roll out, removed votes will now show as a distinct event in the reputation tab on your user profile.