# Change the reputation recalc error message to "once every 24 hours"

Tags: feature-request, error-message, reputation-recalc

Yesterday in the evenings, I foolishly tried to trigger two reputation recalcs within a short time span and received the error message

> Reputation cannot be recalculated more than once per day.

So I tried another recalc in the morning of the next day, only to receive the same error message again. I then found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71678/159019) answer about the recalc feature, stating "*Note that you can only do this once every 24 hours"* (which is more specific than *"once per day"*). And indeed, a few minutes after 24 hours had passed since my last successful recalc, I was allowed to trigger another recalc. Therefore, I suggest to change the error message to

> Reputation cannot be recalculated more than once every 24 hours.

EDIT: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) was [updated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/7238/revisions) to include the "one recalculation every 24 hours" limit. The actual recalc error message, however, still reads *"once per day"*.

Comment: @PopularDemand: It was about 18:35 yesterday. Today my recalc attempts failed at 18:30 and succeeded at 18:40, so I'm quite sure "once every 24 hours" is to be taken literally.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Soon this will no longer be necessary, since recalcs will be a thing of the past.  Instead we will start keeping your reputation in sync at all times, and with a more detailed history available in your profile showing exactly what happened.

You can read more about it here: [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)

Comment: I wanted to suggest adding a moderator-only "status" tag to my question, but found no appropriate one. So I created "status-moot". If I have missed the correct tag, please feel free to retag.

Comment: @lockstep - I'd say *technically* it's [status-declined], but we're fixing the underlying issue here so...yeah, just left it off :)