# Reputation score changed by about 700 points over night

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

I find it strange, and maybe someone can explain this to me.

Yesterday I had a reputation score of **3992**. Today my reputation score is **3302**.

I see no indication why this would have happened when I look at my reputation page.

Comment: There's a "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the reputation page, make sure you have that one checked

Comment: The posts which you've answered/edited would have been removed. Click show removed posts to see them

Comment: I can not see any clue there as well why my points are missing...

Comment: You need to read about [reputation recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc)

Comment: @OzairKafray The reputation recalc is not needed anymore, the reputation should now be reasonably current at all times.

Comment: Reputation recalc does not show anything that explains what happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four big cases where you can lose a lot of reputation at once:

- One of your posts was deleted, this will remove the reputation you gained for that post unless it was a significantly upvoted post on an old question that was only recently deleted. This leaves an entry in your reputation history
- A user was deleted and all his votes were removed. This would usually affect a lot of users at once, and it also leaves an entry in your reputation history.
- There were anomalous votes from another user towards your account and they were invalidated. You should have heard from a moderator about that if it happened, and it also leaves an entry in your history.
- Your account was merged with another account that had voted a lot for you. This removes all the votes between the two merged users, and it is the only case I know that doesn't leave an entry in your reputation history. You should have heard about this from a moderator as well, and would likely be suspended for sock-puppeting.

The only other explanation I can think of is some kind of bug in the reputation code.

Comment: I haven't done anything wrong what I know of, and I haven't heard from a moderator, so I guess there must be a user that was deleted. Thanks for your help. Kind of sucks losing 700 points though.

Comment: @Patrik I doubt that, a deleted user would have left an entry in your reputation history.

Comment: Hmmm. OK. Really weird. Is there any way of getting someone to look at this?

Comment: Just wait for a while and likely someone from SE will see this post (most of them are just waking up now).

Comment: @Patrik - I took a look at your reputation history and I don't see the drop you're reporting. On July 11, your reputation was 3247 and it was  3267 on July 21. At no point do I see it hitting anything above the 3307 you're sitting at right now. There are no merged users, deleted users, or recent deleted questions that I see, so unless there's a bug in the system somewhere, you never had the 3992 points to begin with.

Comment: @BradLarson: I cannot see it either, but I sure had. I was thrilled about reaching 4000 points. I had my browser opened at work, and when I refreshed the page when i arrived this morning, the points dropped.

Comment: @Patrik - I think you might have misread your reputation score yesterday. You had 3292 points yesterday according to the history I see, not 3992.

Comment: If it helps, @Patrik, I've misread my reputation *numerous* times.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible because of deleted posts.

Go to your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936/patrik?tab=reputation&sort=post). And check the "show removed posts" checkbox. You now see the effects of deleted posts.

Comment: I can't see any clue here to why the points are missing. Reputation recalc doesn't show anything usefull either.