# New earned reputation does not add up after Website migration

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Early today Stackoverflow was on read-only mode due to migration, but since it is back new reputations does not add to my total reputation. See the attached screenshot, the expected total reputation for today should be `325` but it is only showing `305`

[image: Screenshot of reputation summary]

**Edit:**

After associating my `meta.stackoverflow.com` account, I got `100` bonus reputation which is added correctly to my total; however still the reputation that I have earned from *upvote* does not show up.

[image]

**Edit:**

I thought it was a bug after the migration, but it is the *normal* daily cap for upvotes reputation (i.e. 200) as answered below, and same as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/why-does-my-reputation-not-add-up?lq=1)

It is not possible to delete my question now, since the answer has already upvotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the first time you hit the rep cap.

Reputation gains from upvotes only are  capped at 200 rep.

See [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: But yesterday I have `220` total reputations from *upvotes*, and it was added correctly, so what is the difference?

Comment: @iTech - No, you didn't. You gained 130 from upvotes and 90 from two accepted answers, totalling 220.

Comment: You are right, I just calculated them now! I thought it was a bug after the migration.

Comment: same story with me